# Can we get a clearer title for the "do not discard" comment button?

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

I was using the Android app earlier, and decided not to post a comment after beginning. When I cancelled, I was mildly confused by the choice I was offered:

[image: screenshot that reads 'discard comment? Nevermind/Discard']

"Nevermind," to me, could also mean "never mind, I don't want to write this comment after all."

Can this be replaced with a simpler and less confusing text? The simplest option would probably be "Do you want to discard your comment? [Yes/No]" (ht Shadow Wizard, Shub)

Comment: Or... more simply: `No` ;)

Comment: Yes/No should also work :-)

Comment: "Sure you want to discard your comment?" [Yes/No] will work as well.

Answer (score -2):

I fail to see a problem there, because, with the "never mind" button meaning "never mind, I don't want to write this comment after all." it would duplicate the "discard" option, and this is quite strange if it would be actually. Therefore I find it quite clear.

I didn't get even confused when I faced this dialog the first time being curious what does that arrow do. I understand "nevermind" as just  "don't do anything, clicked it by mistake".

Comment: I figured it out pretty quickly... But IMHO it would be easier to not need to figure it out at all, and just have it be clear to begin with.

Comment: @Shokhet Maybe, but in this case I find it to be a needless fix.

Comment: @nicael I find it pretty ironic that you're saying this is a 'needless fix' when you're the one renowned for posting very minor bugs! (even if I agree with many of your reported bugs that others find unnecessary)

Comment: @grg lol, this happens :D

Comment: @grgarside I see your point, but to be fair this isn't a bug, it's a word "choice". OP even has "feature-request" not "bug" :)

Comment: @James I know, I was purely referring to nicael's comment.